# Is there any other way to find eigenvalues without finding the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found out that when a given matrix contains mostly constants,the characteristic polynomial also contains these constants and finding the roots is a bit more time-consuming.

I was wondering if there is any other way to find the eigenvalues,apart from computing the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

For example,the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}q & q & 1\\ 1 & q & q \\ 3 & q & q\end{bmatrix}$$

Gives the characteristic polynomial: $$p(\lambda)=2 q^2-2q-\lambda^3+3q\lambda^2-2q^2\lambda+q\lambda+3\lambda$$

How would you find the eigenvalues for that matrix?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. Because otherwise you would be able to compute the eigenvalues of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) $M$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ without knowing its characteristic polynomial. But this characteristic polynomial is $p(x)$ itself and the eigenvalues of $M$ are the roots of $p(x)$.